# Non repeating texture

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I'd like to apply an image texture (a logo) to an object, and don't want to have it repeating/tiling across the whole object.
It seems I'm unable to do it.

I'm using v.2.78 and Blender Render (not Cycles).

Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi :) could you please [add an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199380/edit) showing your current material setup? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure. Thank you!